# RxJS: Backpressure with switchMap producing N values

Tags: rxjs

I am talking to some RESTful search endpoint that involves pagination. The query is triggered by user typing in a search field, and as a result it produces an Observable with N values, corresponding to the N result pages.

The code looks somewhat like the following:

```
function runQueries(queryObservable) {
  return queryObservable
           .debounceTime(500)
           .distinctUntilChanged()
           .switchMap(search);
}

function search(query) {
  return Observable.create(observer => searchInto(observer, query, 0));
}

function searchInto(observer, query, start) {
  runQuery(query, start).subscribe(result => {
    observer.next(result);
    if (hasMorePages(result)) {
      searchInto(observer, query, start + 1);
    } else {
      observer.complete();
    }
  });
}
```

Now, the search requests can take a while and I don't want to retrieve all the pages if user changes the query.

Let's say the search return 3 pages, and user changes the query after one page is loaded. I want to see something like:

```
USER: types query A
CODE: loads page A1
USER: types query B
CODE: loads page B1
CODE: loads page B2
CODE: loads page B3
```

`switchMap` gets half of the job done. The resulting observable has the correct sequence: A1, B1, B2, B3. Great.

However, behind the scenes my recursive search is still running all the queries, putting unnecessary load on the server, network, etc. `switchMap` does discard the "obsolete" results, but it does not prevent the recursive function from doing its work to the end. In other words, it looks like:

```
USER: types query A
CODE: loads page A1   -> returned by search observable
USER: types query B
CODE: loads page A2   -> discarded by search observable
CODE: loads page B1   -> returned by search observable
CODE: loads page B2   -> returned by search observable
CODE: loads page A3   -> discarded by search observable
CODE: loads page B3   -> returned by search observable
```

The sequence of "A" and "B" is random (subject to race conditions), but it doesn't matter.

What am I doing wrong? What is the idiomatic solution to this?

Comment: what do you use for making HTTP requests? In your solutions I don't see where do you cancel Observable. Like in this example https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/r1tahjqe/3/, there is code `return () => request.abort();` which about http request

Comment: @AlexanderT. That's exactly the question, can I "cancel" an Observable? Pass a message in the opposite direction, so the recursive producer knows it should not run any more queries?

I'm making the HTTP requests with Angular2 HTTP or with some custom HTTP client. I don't think it's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switchMap` can only cancel an operation if you return an `Observable`  that is cancelable. Since you are not returning the `Subscription` within `Observable.create` it can't cancel the in-flight operations.

As it stands using `Observable.create` is not really helping you in this case, I would suggest that you make use of the [`expand`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/expand.ts) operator to perform recursive operations instead:

```
function runQueries(queryObservable) {
  return queryObservable
           .debounceTime(500)
           .distinctUntilChanged()
           .switchMap(search);
}

function search(query) {
  //Kicks off the first query
  return runQuery(query, 0)
      //Uses the results of the first query to see if more queries should be made
     .expand((result, idx) => 
       //Continues to execute more queries until `hasMorePages` is false
       hasMorePages(result) ? 
         runQuery(query, idx + 1) : 
         Observable.empty());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`flatMap` is kind enough to unsubscribe from the `Observable` when it kicks off a new "stream". The producer can use the subscription status with `observer.isUnsubscribed` to stop its work:

```
function searchInto(observer, query, start) {
  runQuery(query, start).subscribe(result => {
    observer.next(result);
    if (hasMorePages(result) && !observer.isUnsubscribed) {
      searchInto(observer, query, start + 1);
    } else {
      observer.complete();
    }
  });
}
```