# Get return value from subcribe on Observable

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs, observer-pattern, rxjs5

Using RxJS `5.0.0-rc.1`, I'm trying to communicate my `Observer` and `Observable` in a way similar to [how generators/iterators work](http://www.2ality.com/2015/03/es6-generators.html) by exchanging data using `yield` and `.next()`. The intention is to **get a hold of what a call to `.subscribe` returns** and modify/update following values in my observable stream depending on that.

I'm not entirely sure if this is, at all, possible. Though, I found out that you *can* catch exceptions thrown on `.subscribe` callbacks. The following snippets prints out `"Boom!"`:

```
var source = Observable.create((observer) => {
  try {
    observer.next(42);
  } catch (e) {
    // This will catch the Error
    // thrown on the subscriber
    console.log(e.message);
  }
  observer.complete();
});

source.subscribe(() => {
  throw new Error('Boom!');
});
```

So, what if instead of throwing, the subscriber returns a value? Is there a way for the `Observable` to retrieve it? Perhaps I'm approaching this the wrong way. If so, what's the "reactive" way of doing things in this scenario?

Many thanks.

---

**EDIT**

One possible way I came up with is by providing a callback function on every item in the stream. Something like:

```
var source = Observable.create((observer) => {
  // This will print "{ success: true }"
  observer.next({ value: 42, reply: console.log });
  observer.complete();
});

source.subscribe(({ value, reply }) => {
  console.log('Got', value);
  return reply({ success: true });
});
```

Any other thoughts?

---

**EDIT 2**

Since my original question brought some confusion on what I was trying to achieve, I'll describe my real world scenario. I'm writing the API of a module for managing messages through queues (much like a simplified, in memory, AMQP-RPC mechanism) and I though RxJS would be a good fit.

It works like you would expect: a `Publisher` pushes messages to a queue, which get delivered to a `Consumer`. In term, the `Consumer` can reply to the `Publisher`, which can listen to that response if it's interested.

In an ideal scenario, the API would look something like this:

```
Consumer().consume('some.pattern')
  .subscribe(function(msg) {
    // Do something with `msg`
    console.log(msg.foo);
    return { ok: true };
  });

Publisher().publish('some.pattern', { foo: 42 })
// (optional) `.subscribe()` to get reply from Consumer
```

That example would print `42`.

The logic for replying to the `Publisher` lies within the `Consumer` function. But the actual response comes *from the `.subscribe()`* callback. Which leads me to my original question: how should I go about fetching that returned value from the creator of the stream?

Think of `Consumer#consume()` as:

```
/**
 * Returns an async handler that gets invoked every time
 * a new message matching the pattern of this consumer
 * arrives.
 */
function waitOnMessage(observer) {
  return function(msg) {
    observer.next(msg);
    // Conceptually, I'd like the returned
    // object from `.subscribe()` to be available
    // in this scope, somehow.
    // That would allow me to go like: 
    // `sendToQueue(pubQueue, response);`
  }
}

return Observable.create((observer) => {
  queue.consume(waitOnMessage(observer));
});
```

Does it make any more sense?

Answer (score 2):

There are indeed similarities between generators and observables. As you can see [here](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/), observables (asynchronous sequence of values) are the asynchronous version of iterables (synchronous sequence of values).

Now, a generator is a function which returns an `Iterable`. However, Rxjs `Observable` encloses both a generator - a.k.a producer (that you execute/start by calling `subscribe`) and the produced asynchronous sequence of values (that you observe by passing an `Observer` object). And the `subscribe` call returns a `Disposable` which allows you to stop receiving values (disconnect). So while generators and observables are dual concepts, the APIs to use them differ.

You cannot do two-way communication by default with the rxjs observable API. You probably could manage to do it by constructing yourself the back channel through subjects (note that you MUST have an initial value to kick off the cycle).

```
var backChannel = Rx.Subject();
backChannel.startWith(initialValue).concatMap(generateValue)
  .subscribe(function observer(value){
  // Do whatever
  // pass a value through the backChannel
  backChannel.next(someValue)
})
// generateValue is a function which takes a value from the back channel 
// and returns a promise with the next value to be consumed by the observer.
```

You could consider wrapping that with :

```
function twoWayObsFactory (yield, initialValue) {
  var backChannel = Rx.BehaviorSubject(initialValue);
  var next = backChannel.next.bind(backChannel);
  return {
    subscribe : function (observer) {
      var disposable = backChannel.concatMap(yield)
        .subscribe(function(x) {
           observer(next, x);
        });
      return {
        dispose : function (){disposable.dispose(); backChannel.dispose();}
      }
    }
  }
}

// Note that the observer is now taking an additional parameter in its signature
// for instance
// observer = function (next, yieldedValue) {
//              doSomething(yieldedValue);
//              next(anotherValue);
//            }
// Note also that `next` is synchronous, as such you should avoir sequences
// of back-and-forth communication that is too long. If your `yield` function
// would be synchronous, you might run into stack overflow errors.
// All the same, the `next` function call should be the last line, so order of
// execution in your program is the same independently of the synchronicity of
// the `yield` function
```

Otherwise, the behaviour you describe seems to be that of an asynchronous generator. I never used such, but as this is a proposal for some future version of javascript, I think you can 
already start trying it out with Babel (cf. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration).

**EDIT** :

If you are looking for a loop-back mechanism (less general purpose approach but could very well fits your use case, if what you want to do is simple enough), the `expand` operator could help. To understand its behaviour, please check the [doc](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/expand.md), and the following answers on SO for examples of use in concrete contexts:

- [RxJS: Backpressure with switchMap producing N values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066087/rxjs-backpressure-with-switchmap-producing-n-values/39108106#39108106)
- [Circular Dependencies with RxJS. Modeling spores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037305/circular-dependencies-with-rxjs-modeling-spores/35038057#35038057)
- [How to build an rx poller that waits some interval AFTER the previous ajax promise resolves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856397/how-to-build-an-rx-poller-that-waits-some-interval-after-the-previous-ajax-promi/35857892#35857892)

Basically `expand` allows you to both emit a value downstream and feed that value back at the same time in your producer.

Comment: I like your idea here. Would you show me an example of its usage, please? Perhaps, re-implement my simple sample code on the original question using your `twoWayObsFactory`?

Comment: I was just thinking, have you checked the `expand` operator (Rxjs v4)? It allows you to have a feedback loop. Your simple code by the way is not a really good example of the problem that you describe. You are not sending any value back to your observable in that example for what I see.

Comment: You _are_ sending a value. A whole object, in fact: `{ success: true }`. The observable does nothing, except printing it - but, change `reply` to whatever you want it to be and you can manipulate the response in any way. I'm talking about my second example, under **EDIT**.

Comment: I think that you are confused by the terminology. `reply` is a callback, i.e. a function, you are not sending any values from the observer to the observable (`source` in your example). This is in no way related to the `next` and `yield` API for generators. `next` really does pass a value to the generator which can use it or not to produce its next value. So there is no two-way data flow in your example. If that's all you want to do, don't subscribe, just map, `obs.map(value => doSomething).map(value => doSomethingElse).subscribe(function(){doNothing})`

Comment: All right, fair enough. Could you take a look at my edits on the OP, please? I've included a full description of my scenario. Thanks.

Comment: alright then you should use a subject for the back channel and subscribe your publisher to that subject. Your publisher is both a producer and a listener, and that is exactly what a subject is, so your publisher should be a subject too. Have a look here too : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/howdoi/eventemitter.md. Can't spend much more time on this sorry.